# UICollectionViewCell with subview keeps redrawing itself in cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation

I have a view where I do some drawing. I add a shape layer as a sublayer of the view's layer, then an image view as a subview of the view, and then curve the corners of the imageview's layer. It all works perfectly.

Now i need to use this view in a collectionviewcell, where i can set the image dynamically.

If i perform the work in draw rect it draws it self over and over on top of the other as the collection view scrolls.

I've tried a few other things, like creating a property on the cell for a uiimage, setting that as the imageview's image, and doing the drawing in a setter for it.

Does anyone have a suggestion about how to do this?

Update: Here's an example of the kind of thing im doing in the view

```
- (void)simplifiedDrawWithImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    CGRect circleRect = self.bounds;

    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circleRect];
    circleLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath;

    circleLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, shadowScale * length);
    circleLayer.shadowOpacity = .5;
    circleLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadiusScale * length;

    [self.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    // size appropriately
    [self addSubview:imageView];

    CALayer *imageLayer = imageView.layer;
    [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [imageLayer setCornerRadius:((imageView.frame.size.width - innerRing / 2) / 2)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

At least, it SOUNDS like the same problem.

Comment: But would this have to do all of the drawing each and every time?

Answer (score 0):

In your UICollectionViewCell, override `-prepareForReuse` and remove the previous image.

**Update:**

In your code, you have this line: `[self.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];` which is adding a layer of drawing TO YOUR CELL. So later when you create a UIImageView and assign it an image, you still have created a drawing in the cell itself.

When that cell is recycled, that layer is still there, and then you add it again. Don't draw that layer on self, create that in a view then add that to the cell.

Comment: OK, so I understand: Why is it that if it were say, just a uiimageview in the cell, that doesn't need to be cleared out? Seems to be fundamentally the same thing.

Comment: Because in that case you're probably setting the `.image` on the UIImageView each time, which means it's always the last `.image` being shown. Does that make sense?

Comment: To clarify: In your case, you're constantly adding layers, you never remove the previous ones. This cell is recycled, which means you're adding layers onto the old layers.

Comment: Ok, let me try this approach and I'll let you know what happens

Comment: I added more clarification of exactly what I think is happening here.

Comment: Ok so break the circle layer drawing out to a view and then place the image view on top of that? Where would i init this new circle view, because i pass some arguments in that alter the appearance.

Comment: In that method, I was create a UIView first that is the frame of self.bounds. And then I would do that layer addition in that UIView and then add that UIView to self.